# What's wrong with this declaration?

Tags: c, pthreads, declaration, void-pointers

It goes like this, the fourth, the fifth:

```
void * copyFile( void * arg )
{
    struct dirent *ent = (dirent *)arg;
}
```

GCC tells me `'dirent' undeclared (first use in this function)`.

Before you ask, the argument is `void *` because it's being passed to a pthread, and that's just the way I was taught to do it, and because this is my first time threading (it hurts), I'm just doing what I'm told because my understanding here is weak at best.

Comment: GCC has told you `'dirent' undeclared`, then declare it?

Comment: You need to include the header that defines `dirent`: `#include <dirent.h>`

Comment: I have included it. Other portions of the code use it, and it didn't complain about them.

Answer (score 5):

unless you `typedef` the structure you need:

```
struct dirent *ent = (struct dirent *)arg;
```

Answer (score 2):

As mux has explained you need to use

`struct dirent *ent = (struct dirent *)arg;`

I just want to make it clear why you have to do this. When you declare a structure we do one of the following

**1. Without typedef**

```
struct my_struct         // <----- Name of the structure(equivalent to datatype)
     {
    int x;
    int y;
     } hello;          // <------Variable of type my_struct
```

Now you can access using:

1. `hello.x=100;`
2. Declaring a new variable can be done using

`struct my_struct new_variable; (new_variable is new variable of type my_struct)`

**2. Now using typedef**

```
typedef struct my_struct
  {
     int x;
     int y;
   } hello;        //<----- Hello is a typedef for **struct my_struct**
```

So when you do

```
hello new_var; //  <-------- new_var is a new variable of type my_struct

hello.x      //  <-------- Here hello refers to the datatype and not the variable
```

Therefore the variable dirent can mean different things in ***different contexts***:-

If you don't mention the struct the compiler will assume it is in typedef context and hence will find that the variable is undeclared.

Hence you need to mention it directly as pointed by mux.